# Unable to Move Mailbox to new Database - 0 of 0 Succeeded

Tags: migration, exchange-2013, mailbox

I'm selecting one mailbox to move to a new mailbox database in Exchange 2013, and when I start the Migration job in ECP it shows one Mailbox, but a few moments later when refreshing the job it changes to 0 mailboxes and then completes in an apparent normal state with 0 of 0 succeeded. I deleted this job and all previous ones from the list and tried again - same result.  I deleted the job again and moved on to investigate.

Digging deeper in the console I ran Get-MoveRequest and received the following:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-moverequest

DisplayName                                    Status                    TargetDatabase
-----------                                    ------                    --------------
SystemMailbox{8cc370d3-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94b... Completed
WARNING: The object support.local/Users/SystemMailbox{8cc370d3-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94bd0641a9} has been corrupted, and
it's in an inconsistent state. The following validation errors happened:
WARNING: Database is mandatory on UserMailbox.
```

The mentioned SystemMailbox appears to be pretty old and was "Disabled" in AD. I tried enabling and disabling the account again, but no joy.  I am not able to remove the request as I cannot identify it, nor have I had any results from repairing the source and destination folder of my migration using:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>New-MailboxRepairRequest -Database CleanDB -CorruptionType ProvisionedFolder,SearchFolder,Aggre
gateCounts,Folderview
```

I am at a hard stop as it would seem the errors above are preventing my migration job from completeing and I have not been able to over come what I have found so far.  Any advice?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by simply deleting the SystemMailbox mentioned above as it seemed to be orphaned in the system.  After, I could migrate mailboxes to and from databases normally and have seen no adverse effects or errors in the application logs.

Note: I did not have to run PrepareAD from the setup.exe.

I hope this helps someone else that has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to check the **database** of "SystemMailbox{8cc370d3-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94bd0641a9}":

```
Get-Mailbox -AuditLog | FL Alias,ServerName,Database
```

If it remains display a warning "*Database is mandatory on UserMailbox*":

1. Open **ADUC** and enable **Advanced Features**, find "**SystemMailbox{8cc370d3-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94bd0641a9}**" and open Properties.
2. Switch to Attributes Editor and find "**homeMDB**".
3. Copy this value from other mailbox which store in same database, and replace the value for problematic mailbox.

If it remain exists, we may need to recreate it by **PrepareAD**.
Note: the AD account of those system mailboxes are disabled by default.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I am getting the follow error when running your recommened command: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AuditLog'.  I am running the console as Administrator as well.

Comment: Exchange 2013? Which CU now?